# Finding hidden data

Tags: internal-storage

I have an app that has 4 GB of video data, But I cant find it even with the hidden files showing. I want to move them to my SD card, How do I find them ?

Comment: They're probably stored with the app's data, where you can see it only if you have root access. As you don't say which app it is it cannot be said for certain, but probability is high.

Comment: The app is Linkin Learning

Comment: You need root to check. For most cases possible locations are /sdcard/Android/data/[App name]/ or /data/data/[App name]/.